# std::map thread-safety and iterator invalidation

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I'm trying to determine if the following sample code is thread-safe:

```
std::map<K, V> myMap;

void foo() {
   myMap[k]; // Construct a new key-value pair with key `k`.
}

void bar() {
   auto it = myMap.find(x);
   if (it != myMap.end()) {
      std::lock_gaurd<std::mutex> lg(...);
      // do something with *it
   }
}
```

There are no removals taking place (atleast until the program is terminating), the only operations are adding elements in `foo` and iterating over them in `bar`. Function `foo` will get called from one thread and `bar` will get called in multiple threads, all concurrently.

Now, I understand that the STL containers are not thread-safe and I'm doing a non-const operation concurrently using `myMap::operator[]`. What I'm confused about is since STL `find` doesn't change the underlying map, and because `myMap::operator[]` doesn't invalidate iterators nor references, would this still be considered unsafe? I see a bit of a clash in my thinking: should I be worried because `operator[]` is non-const and thus I'm doing concurrent changes to the data structure, or can I consider this safe since it won't invalidate my iterator?

Comment: The invariants are valid before and after calling a non-const function, but they are not guaranteed to be valid *during* the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to be suspicious. You can't call `myMap[k]` and `myMap.find(x)` from different threads at the same time.

With containers, you can safely do one of the following at a time:

1. Call const member functions from *any* number of threads concurrently, or
2. Call a non-const member function from exactly one thread.

Since `operator[]` is not `const`, you have to guard it with a mutex or otherwise ensure that you're not calling any other member functions at the same time.

Comment: one addition: just adding the lock_guard in `foo()` won't be sufficient though since `bar()` locks too late, if `foo()` is executed concurrently. example: `foo()` could hold the lock, `bar()` might still execute `.find()`, then `foo()` would insert something into the map - invalidating the `it` of `bar()` -> probably crash

Comment: "Invalidating the it of bar". This is probably the source of my confusion. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at, "no iterators or references are invalidated." Then shouldn't it not be invalid?

Comment: @AnthonyCalandra: Correct, `it` won't be invalidated. But you have to wrap the `myMap.find(x);` in a lock and the `myMap.end()` in a lock (maybe it's safe, but the standard doesn't say so!) and you might as well lock the whole function at that point, rather than locking each section of it piecemeal.